# How to renew shared subscription key in azure api management gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm using `<log-to-event-hub>` policy to log all the request and responses to event-hubs.This policy requires a `logger-id` which refers to the event hub where our logs will be streamed.To create this logger I referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs . Where we send a `PUT` request to `https://{your service}.management.azure-api.net/loggers/{new logger name}?api-version=2017-03-01` with the `SharedAccessSignature` token generated in the Management API section API Management Service.Now this token is valid only for 30days.That means the`<log-to-event-hub>` policy can log to this event-hub only for 30 days.

Today the `SharedAccessSignature` got expired.So all of my API's started throwing a `500 internal server error`.How to renew this `SharedAccessSignature` automatically so that when its about to expire it automatically gets renewed with the new `SharedAccessSignature`.

I did not find any solution so I deleted the event-hub and created a new one with the new shared key.I will be storing all my logs in this event-hub so it should be running up everytime.Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please ask for more details

Comment: from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication#ProgrammaticallyCreateToken. You can programmatically create token so you may want to create some script that runs every X days to generate a new token ???

Comment: Ok...but where will I put the newly generated token.I tried generating a new token from the azure portal.But when I tried sending a PUT request to azure-api with the new token ,it says the entity with same name already exist.Because the logger with the name already  exist but its expired.

Comment: Will I have to create a new logger with the new key always.That way I have to change the name of the logger in the event-hub policy always

Comment: you are doing it all manually from the portal ? you probably want to create/update the logger from ARM template ?

Comment: Hey Thomas can you walk me through the process of upadting the logger.I'm actually new to Azure.So please help.And also I have no idea about ARM templates.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up tokens here. The token you generate in "Management API" section is used to authenticate your call to create logger. This token is only needed if you choose to make that call via our direct api (xxx.management.azure-api.net) and not via ARM. This PUT call needs to be done only once to create a logger. The credentials that are used to talk to eventhub are passed inside payload of that call, see "credentials" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/logger/createorupdate#request-body. And it's those credentials you may need to rotate. See eventhub docs on how to create those credentials.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you are talking about the `connectionString` in the shared access policies of the event hub.Ok if the connectionString url is regenerated then also it gives me the same internal server error.Can you walk me through the process to create a logger without it being expired.

Comment: @Rahuljhawar, if the connectionstring/access key is rotated, it will expire.

Comment: @Thomas when I try to update the logger with the new credentials it tells me that the authorization header is missing.So for every update shall I create a new SharedAccessSignature key.